# How to make a reminder on the lock screen

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, lock-screens

I would like to create a reminder on the lock screen so I can see it everytime I tried to use my mobile.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have Jelly Bean; how about a lock-screen widget? They're very useful and there are tons of them.

Note by default Lock Screen Widgets are disabled, go to the `Settings` app on your device, select `Security` and look for the `"Enable Widgets"` option

You could use [Google Keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep&hl=en)  as an example:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ampercent.com](http://www.ampercent.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/keep_3.jpeg))</sub>

I use  [Dash Clock widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.dashclock&hl=en) on my lock screen and homescreen! It's a wonderful, simple widget. The advantage is you can add loads of extensions, for example:  [Dash Clock NOTES](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vdlow.dashclocknote&hl=en)  which sounds exactly right for what you need!

Here's an example:

http://cdn7.staztic.com/app/a/2260/2260711/dashclock-notes-extension-903772-0-s-307x512.jpg

There are numerous notebook style applications, and I, obviously, cannot provide an exhaustive list. Why not shop around (many are free) and ensure they have a lock-screen widget option?!

Comment: It seems that lock screen widgets were removed in Lollipop: http://www.androidauthority.com/lock-screen-widgets-android-lollipop-611516/

Answer (score 1):

**Owner Info** is a possible workaround.

```
Settings > Security > Owner Info
```

It shows an arbitrary string on the lock screen.

Downsides:

- not super visible
- newlines don't render as newlines, only spaces